# $lookup and get count under certain conditions MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have 2 collections for handling chat

1. For chat rooms
2. For chat Messages

Sample data for chatRooms is as follows

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "_id": "5a606ab0116e2c164b25ef33",
        "topic": "akhil Ben chat",
        "topicDesc": "question 1",
        "roomName": "benakhil777akhil",
        "createdOn": "2018-01-18T09:36:48.231Z",
        "participants": [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a4dbdaab46b426863e7ead3",
        "topic": "test",
        "topicDesc": "test123",
        "roomName": "benakhil777test",
        "createdOn": "2018-01-04T05:37:46.088Z",
        "participants": [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]}
```

Sample Data for chatMessages is as follows

```
{"data": [

    {
        "_id": "5a62281ea0652120a6668bae",
        "topic": "akhil Ben chat",
        "roomName": "benakhil777akhil",
        "message": "test 1",
        "__v": 0,
        "readStatus": [
            {
                "recipient": "ben",
                "_id": "5a62281ea0652120a6668bb0",
                "status": true
            },
            {
                "recipient": "akhil777",
                "_id": "5a62281ea0652120a6668baf",
                "status": true
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2018-01-19T17:17:18.456Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a622866a0652120a6668bb1",
        "topic": "akhil Ben chat",
        "roomName": "benakhil777akhil",
        "message": "Test 2",
        "__v": 0,
        "readStatus": [
            {
                "recipient": "ben",
                "_id": "5a622866a0652120a6668bb3",
                "status": false
            },
            {
                "recipient": "akhil777",
                "_id": "5a622866a0652120a6668bb2",
                "status": true
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2018-01-19T17:18:30.396Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a62287ca0652120a6668bb4",
        "topic": "akhil Ben chat",
        "roomName": "benakhil777akhil",
        "message": "test 3",
        "__v": 0,
        "readStatus": [
            {
                "recipient": "ben",
                "_id": "5a62287ca0652120a6668bb6",
                "status": false
            },
            {
                "recipient": "akhil777",
                "_id": "5a62287ca0652120a6668bb5",
                "status": true
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2018-01-19T17:18:52.018Z"
    }
]}
```

In the above JSON readStatus store the status, which the user read the message or not. so that i can count the unread messages by a user for each chat room.
The status inside the readStatus holds the read status of message, true for message is read.
There are two rooms *benakhil777akhil* and *benakhil777test*.

What i want to get is the number of unread messages for each room by a user say *ben*

Also there is userDetails collection 
say,

```
 [{
   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
   "username": "ben",
   "name": "Ben S",
   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
},{
   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
   "username": "akhil777",
   "name": "Akhil Clement",
   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
}]
```

this will be the user details collection

and output JSON i need is like.

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "_id": "5a606ab0116e2c164b25ef33",
        "topic": "akhil Ben chat",
        "topicDesc": "question 1",
        "roomName": "benakhil777akhil",
        "createdOn": "2018-01-18T09:36:48.231Z",
        "participants": [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "participantDetails":[{
                   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
                   "username": "ben",
                   "name": "Ben S",
                   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
                 },{
                   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
                   "username": "akhil777",
                   "name": "Akhil Clement",
                   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
        }],
        "unreadCount": 2,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a4dbdaab46b426863e7ead3",
        "topic": "test",
        "topicDesc": "test123",
        "roomName": "benakhil777test",
        "createdOn": "2018-01-04T05:37:46.088Z",
        "participants": [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "participantDetails":[{
                   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
                   "username": "ben",
                   "name": "Ben S",
                   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
                 },{
                   "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
                   "username": "akhil777",
                   "name": "Akhil Clement",
                   "email": "qwerty@123.com",
        }],
        "unreadCount": 0,
        "__v": 0
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this aggregation pipeline

```
db.rooms.aggregate(
    [
        {$match : {participants : 'ben'}},
        {$lookup : { 
            from : "chats", 
            localField : "roomName", 
            foreignField:"roomName",
            as :"out"
            }
        },
        {$unwind : {
                path: "$out",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {$unwind : {
                path: "$out.readStatus",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {$addFields : {
                isMatch : { $and : [
                    { $eq : ["$out.readStatus.recipient" , "ben" ] } , { $eq : [ "$out.readStatus.status" , false ] } ]
                }
            }
        },
        {$group : {
                _id : {
                    _id : "$_id" , 
                    topic : "$topic",
                    topicDesc : "$topicDesc",
                    createdOn : "$createdOn",
                    participants : "$participants",
                    roomName : "$roomName"
                },
                unreadCount : { $sum : { $cond : [ "$isMatch" , 1, 0 ]  } }
            }
        },
        {$sort : {unreadCount : -1}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

result

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : "5a606ab0116e2c164b25ef33",
        "topic" : "akhil Ben chat",
        "topicDesc" : "question 1",
        "createdOn" : "2018-01-18T09:36:48.231Z",
        "participants" : [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "roomName" : "benakhil777akhil"
    },
    "unreadCount" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : "5a4dbdaab46b426863e7ead3",
        "topic" : "test",
        "topicDesc" : "test123",
        "createdOn" : "2018-01-04T05:37:46.088Z",
        "participants" : [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "roomName" : "benakhil777test"
    },
    "unreadCount" : 0
}
```

**EDIT** since `addFields` is not available in 3.2.17

```
{$group : {
                _id : {
                    _id : "$_id" , 
                    topic : "$topic",
                    topicDesc : "$topicDesc",
                    createdOn : "$createdOn",
                    participants : "$participants",
                    roomName : "$roomName"
                },
                unreadCount : { $sum : { $cond : [ { $and : [
                    { $eq : ["$out.readStatus.recipient" , "ben" ] } , { $eq : [ "$out.readStatus.status" , false ] } ]
                } , 1, 0 ]  } }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT-2** added `$project`

```
    {$project : 
        { 
            "_id" : "$_id._id",
            "topic" : "$_id.topic",
            "topicDesc" : "$_id.topicDesc",
            "createdOn" : "$_id.createdOn",
            "participants" : "$_id.participants",
            "roomName" : "$_id.roomName",
            "unreadCount" : "$unreadCount"
        }
    }
```

Comment: $addFields is not available currently using mongo version  3.2.17

Comment: {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "5a4dbdaab46b426863e7ead3",
                "topic": "test",
                "topicDesc": "test123",
                "createdOn": "2018-01-04T05:37:46.088Z",
                "participants": [
                    "ben",
                    "akhil777"
                ],
                "roomName": "benakhil777test"
            },
            "unreadCount": 0
        }

Comment: getting JSON like this.\

Comment: need like this {
        "_id": "5a4dbdaab46b426863e7ead3",
        "topic": "test",
        "topicDesc": "test123",
        "roomName": "benakhil777test",
        "createdOn": "2018-01-04T05:37:46.088Z",
        "participants": [
            "ben",
            "akhil777"
        ],
        "unreadCount": 0,
        "__v": 0
    }

Comment: one question, How we can populate the user details from a user collection with participants as [username] //array of usernames.

Comment: say, [{
       "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
       "username": "ben",
       "name": "Ben S",
       "email": "qwerty@123.com",
    },{
       "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
       "username": "akhil",
       "name": "Akhil Clement",
       "email": "qwerty@123.com",
    }]
this will be the user details collection

Comment: can you post a new question with problem and expected results?

Comment: you shouldn't be updating the questions, it has to be a new one in SO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163567/discussion-between-akhil-clement-and-saravana).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to use below aggregation.

`$cond` with input criteria to check for read status flag, output 1 when false 0 when true.

inner `$sum` to count unread values in each chat message with outer $sum to sum the unread values across all matching chat messages.

```
db.chatRooms.aggregate(
[{
  "$match":{"participants":"ben"}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"chatMessages",
    "localField":"roomName",
    "foreignField":"roomName",
    "as":"chatMessages"
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "topic":1,
    "topicDesc":1,
    "roomName":1,
    "createdOn":1,
    "participants":1,
    "unreadCount":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$chatMessages",
          "as":"chatMessage",
          "in":{
            "$sum":{
              "$map":{
                "input":"$$chatMessage.readStatus",
                "as":"mChatMessage",
                "in":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$$mChatMessage.status",false]},1,0]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: one question, How we can populate the user details from a user collection with participants as [username] //array of usernames.

Comment: say, [{
       "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
       "username": "ben",
       "name": "Ben S",
       "email": "qwerty@123.com",
    },{
       "_id": "59e6d6ba02e11e1814481022",
       "username": "akhil",
       "name": "Akhil Clement",
       "email": "qwerty@123.com",
    }]
this will be the user details collection

Answer (score 0):

result JSON with user details.

```
db.chatRooms.aggregate(
     [
                {$match : {participants : 'ben'}},
                { $unwind : {
                        path: "$participants",
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                    }
                },
                { $lookup: {
                    from:"users",
                    localField:"participants",
                    foreignField:"username",
                    as:"userData"
                    }
                },
                { $lookup: {
                    from:"chatmessages",
                    localField:"roomName",
                    foreignField:"roomName",
                    as:"out"
                    }
                },

                { $unwind : {
                        path: "$out",
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                    }
                },
                { $unwind : {
                        path: "$out.readStatus",
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                    }
                },
                { $group : {
                        _id : {
                            _id : "$_id" , 
                            topic : "$topic",
                            topicDesc : "$topicDesc",
                            createdOn : "$createdOn",
                            roomName : "$roomName"
                        },
                        participants : {$addToSet :  "$participants" } ,  
                        participantDetails : {$addToSet : {$arrayElemAt : ["$userData", 0]}},
                        unreadCount : {
                            $sum : { 
                                $cond : [ {
                                 $and : [
                                            { $eq : ["$out.readStatus.recipient" , "ben" ] } , 
                                            { $eq : [ "$out.readStatus.status" , false ] } 
                                        ]
                                    } , 1, 0 
                                    ]  
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                }
                ,
                { $project : 
                    { 
                        _id : "$_id._id",
                        topic : "$_id.topic",
                        topicDesc : "$_id.topicDesc",
                        createdOn : "$_id.createdOn",
                        participants : "$_id.participants",
                        roomName : "$_id.roomName",
                        unreadCount : "$unreadCount",
                        participants : 1 ,  
                        participantDetails : 1
                    }
                }

            ])
```